# Python Connect 4 check for winners (processing 2)

Tags: python, processing

So I'm trying to make a simple Python connnect 4 game on Processing 2, and now I'm trying to make the critical algorithm to check for the winner of a single round. It's not like tic-tac-toe, so I'm not sure where to start. If I should ask somewhere else, tell me as well.

Basically, every time a player places a piece, after the board refreshes the game checks if there are any four consecutive pieces in any direction (horizontally, vertically, diagonally). If not, the game continues. If SO, the game switches to the winning screen.

This is my code so far (remember, this is Python, and # is comment):

```
mode = "win" #initial mode, should be "instruktion" but can be changed for testing
wires=loadFont ("Gulim-64.vlw")
kek = 1337#the score limit variable

points1 = 0 #player 1's score
points2 = 0 #player 2's score
skore1 = points1 #player 1's score as displayed on screen
skore2 = points2 #player 2's score as displayed on screen

win1 = 0 #player 1 wins a round
win2 = 0 #player 2 wins a round
win1text = "Player 1 wins round!"
win2text = "Player 2 wins round!"

viktory1 = 0
viktory2 = 0 #conditionals

viktoryspeech1 = "Player 1 is winner!" #player 1 wins
viktoryspeech2 = "Player 2 is winner!" #player 2 wins

stabber = 0 #y axis, adapting mouseY
jabber = 0 #x axis, adapting mouseX
turn = 1 #1 is player 1, 2 is player 2 

ohbabyatriple = loadImage("mlgdew.png") #**** HER RIGHT IN THE *****

board = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ]

#board = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ]

def setup():
    size(1100,800)

def draw():    
    global mode,viktory1,viktory2
    textFont(wires,100)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    if mode == "instruktion":#the welcome screen with instructions
        background(200,200,200)
        textSize(100)
        fill(31,73,125)
        text ("Welkom!",350,125)
        textSize(40)
        text("To Konnekt 4!",400,195)
        text ("INSTRUKTIONS",390,265)
        textSize(30)
        #the following is instructional text
        text ("1. Two players will first decide on a skore",290,320)
        text ("2. To drop a piece, klik on a space on the bord",260,360)
        text ("3. First player to konnekt 4 in any direktion wins the round",200,400)
        text ("4. First player to reach skore limit wins the game",250,440)
        text ("5. To enter a skore limit, from 1-9, press the respektiv" ,200,480)
        text ("   number on the keyboard.",370,510)
        text ("WARNING: WATCH WHAT SKORE YOU PICK.",240,550)
        text ("AND NEVER PRESS 'X'",400,590) #shmuck bait 
    if mode == "game":#the main game interface
        global board
        if viktory1 == 1:
            mode = "kongrats"
        elif viktory2 ==1:
            mode = "kongrats"
        elif viktory1 ==1 and viktory2 == 1:
            mode = "kill"
        background(200,200,200)
        rectMode(CENTER)
        fill(31,73,125)
        textSize(100)
        text("Konnekt 4",300,100)
        text ("I",160,300)
        textSize(60)
        text("Skore",90,200)
        textSize(80)
        text(skore1,100,290)
        text(skore2,200,290)
        noFill()
        translate(400,230) #shift the board, due to nature of generation

        #generating board
        for y in range(6): #y axis
            for x in range(7): #x axis
                if board[y][x] == 1 and turn!=0:
                    fill(137,2,6)
                elif board[y][x] == 2 and turn!=0:
                    fill(6,2,137)
                elif board[y][x] == 0:
                    noFill()

                rect(x*100,y*80,100,80)
    #each tile is 100x80

    if mode == "win":
        global ohbabyatriple,win1,win2,win1text,win2text
        background(200,200,200)
        textSize(100)
        fill(31,73,125)
        if win1 ==1:
            text(win1text,130,100)
        elif win2 ==1:
            text(win2text,130,100)
        else:
            text("Oh hi, tester!",300,100)
        textSize(40)
        text("Press E to continue",370,175)
        image(ohbabyatriple,200,300)
        image(ohbabyatriple,875,300)
        image(ohbabyatriple,530,300)

    if mode == "draw":
        global ohbabyatriple
        background(200,200,200)
        textSize(100)
        fill(31,73,125)
        text("It's a draw!",310,100)
        textSize(40)
        text("Press E to continue",370,175)
        image(ohbabyatriple,200,300)
        image(ohbabyatriple,875,300)
        image(ohbabyatriple,530,300)

    if mode =="kongrats": #victory screen
        background(200,200,200)
        textSize(100)
        fill(31,73,125)
        text("Kongratulations!",200,100)
        textSize(60)
        if viktory1 ==1:#player 1's win
            text (viktoryspeech1,310,200)
            text ("Have a nice day!",330,280)
        elif viktory2 ==1:#player 2's win
            text (viktoryspeech2,310,200)
            text ("Have a nice day!",330,280)
        else:
            text ("Oh, this is just a test then?",200,200)
            #^ because you normally only get the victory screen after one player wins

    if mode =="OHGODWHY?!":#Shouldn't have pressed it.
        doomedbirds= loadImage("birds_nooooo.jpg")
        ffffuuuu = loadImage ("self_destruct.png")

        background(200,200,200)
        textSize(100)
        fill(31,73,125)
        text("YOU FOOL!",300,100)
        text("YOU DOOMED US ALL!",22,222)
        text("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",22,333)
        image(doomedbirds,560,420)
        image(ffffuuuu,100,420)
        mode = "kill"

    if mode =="kill":#part of the don't-press-the-x code
        exit()

def keyPressed():
    global mode
    global kek
    global win1, win2, viktory1, viktory2
    if key in '123456789' and key != 0 and mode == "instruktion":
        kek = int (key)
        mode = "game"
    if key in 'eE' and mode == "win" or key in 'eE' and mode == "draw":
        if win1 ==1 and points1 != kek:
            win1 =0
        elif win2 == 1 and points2 != kek:
            win1 = 0
        elif points1 ==kek:
            viktory1 = 1
        elif points2 == kek:
            viktory2 = 1

        mode = "game"


    #WARNING: SELF DESTRUCT CODE
    if key in 'xX':
        mode = "OHGODWHY?!"

def mousePressed():
    global jabber, stabber, turn
    stabber = (mouseY-190)/80 #y axis
    jabber =(mouseX-350)/100 #x axis  

    if mode == "game" and stabber >=0 and stabber <=5 and jabber >=0 and jabber<=6 and board[stabber][jabber] == 0: 
        board[stabber][jabber] = turn
        print turn   #extra info
        #color that cell with player's color
        if turn == 1:
            turn = 2
        elif turn == 2:
            turn = 1
        #cycling turns
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What code would I use to check for  4 consecutive pieces in any direction; I'm trying to put it in the def draw(): function. The board uses a 2d array to store a 7x6 (or 6x7 idk) set of numbers, and the def draw draws the interface and visualizes that array and board (I made sure it was accurate).

Comment: ...Each click cycles between player 1 and 2 (turn =1 is player 1, red, turn=2 is player 2, which is blue), I want the board to try and detect any 4 consecutive pieces from either player (four 2's or four 1's in any direction?) every time the board is redrawn; if there is no consecutive, the game goes on.

Comment: I don't have time to read through your program, but here is a general tip: If easilly implemented, and more complex solutions are harder to accomplish, always try bruteforce first unless you are sure that a bruteforce solution isn't sufficient. In this program, I would loop over all pieces, and for each piece, check out all 8 directions, and add together opposing directions (consecutive pieces at -90 and + 90 deg etc.). If that length is longer than 4, return success.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I believe, is the function I think you're missing (needs to be checked out more carefully, maybe with `print` statements &c, but though there may be off-by-one's &c I think it's the right general idea):

```
def fours(fourthings):
    asaset = set(fourthings)
    return asaset.pop() if len(asaset)==1 else 0

def winner(board):
    """ board is a list of `nrows` list,
        each of them a lis of `ncols` columns.
        A cell is `0` to mean empty, else some other
        value; if 4 in a rows (horz, vert, diag) are
        the same non-0 value, that's the result of
        the function; otherwise, the result is 0. """
    nrows = len(board)
    ncols = len(board[0])
    # check horizontals
    for row in board:
        for i in range(ncols-4):
            if fours(row[i:i+4)):
                return row[i]
    # check verticals
    for i in range(ncols):
        for j in range(nrows-4):
            if fours(board[k][i] for k in range(j:j+4)):
                return board[j][i]
    # check NW -> SE diagonals
    for i in range(ncols-4):
        for j in range(nrows-4):
            if fours(board[i+k][j+k] for k in range(4)):
                return board[j][i]
    # check NE -> SW diagonals
    for i in range(3, ncols):
        for j in range(nrows-4):
            if fours(board[i-k][j+k] for k in range(4)):
                return board[j][i]
```

Once made correct in off-by-one terms, it can be improved by removing repetition -- those for/for/if/return blocks of four lines are **very** repetitious and should be factored our into a nested function...